# how do i add a edit, delete, details and create new icon in @html.actionLink in mvc

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

This is html of mvc and this is my format on html:

```
 1. @*@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ActivityDepreciationTypeId })*@ 

 2. @*@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ActivityDepreciationTypeId })*@ 

 3.@*@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ActivityDepreciationTypeId }) |*@

 4. @*@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")*@
```

Answer (score 0):

lets say that for example

@Html.ActionLink(" Login", "Index", new { @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-log-in" })

Comment: that for example you can remove it, just take a look now